# How to separate 2 variables in awk print with echo?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I did a small test to echo everything in my .txt named portal.
When writing in terminal I want the script to echo all with the name entered but I only show the first variable.

```
input=$1

  for portal in $(grep $input /etc/portals | sed '/^#/ d' | awk '{print $1, $2}');

  do
    echo -e "\e[1;32m "$portal" \e[0m";
    exit 0
    done

else
    echo -e "\e[1;31m --> Wrong Input <-- \e[0m"
    exit 1
    done

fi
```

=============

The code works but only $1 gets printed and not the $2.
IF I change the code to : awk '{print $1 $2}' then the output is $1$2 with no tab or spacing between variables.
 =================================

How can I separate the variables so the echo is shown :

test1 [tab/space] test2

Comment: Well let's see... your `for` loop iterates over the whitespace separated tokens in the output from the command in `$(...)` and the loop body contains `exit 0` - it should be obvious why only the first gets printed

Comment: @steeldriver thank you!
Can you please explain why : awk '{print $3"\t"$2}'

Dont give output with tab?

Comment: Because tab is also a whitespace separator - so the for loop sets `portal` to whatever `$1` evaluates to and the script prints that and exits

Comment: @steeldriver how can I get the tab to work between variables? I tried google but all the examples wont work. I removed the exit 0 also.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you are actually trying to do, along with **testable** code (where is the `if` to go with your `else` and `fi` for example) and samples of the inputs and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# exit if input is empty.
[[ -z $1 ]] && exit 1

# Check in the file /etc/portals for 
# the existens of the word "$1" and place 
# first word in "$a" and rest in "$b".
while read -r a b; do
    printf %s\\t%s\\n $a "$b" 
done < <(grep -P "^(?!#).*$1" /etc/portals)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this?